# How to approximate Riemann integrable function by step functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following: $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is integrable, and it follows that there exist sequences of functions $\varphi_k$ and $\varphi^k$ with $\varphi_k \leq f \leq \varphi^k$ such that $\int f dx = \lim_k \int \varphi_k dx = \lim_k \int \varphi^k dx$.

My attempt is to first divide $[a,b]$ into $2$ pieces of equal length,$[a,\frac{b+a}{2}]$,$[\frac{b+a}{2},b]$, then take the supremum of $f$ on every piece to be the value of $\varphi^1$. Keep doing this for every piece I get. Then I can get a decreasing sequence $\varphi^n$. Now to prove that $\lim_k \int \varphi^k dx = \int f dx$, which equals the $inf$ of its upper sums. Using the definition of $inf$ I get, given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists$ a partition $P$ such that $\int f dx \leqslant U(p,f) < \int f dx + \epsilon$, then I want to show that for sufficiently large $n$, $\int \varphi^n dx \leqslant  U(p,f)$. But I do not know how, can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: what's U ? it seems that you can get the same inequality for $\int \phi^k$

Comment: It is upper sum

Comment: what is an upper sum ? you have a sequence of finite sum, if $U$ is already a limit there is something wrong. btw did you use your definition of riemann integral somewhere ?

Comment: Show that for every $\delta > 0$ you have $\int \varphi^n\,dx < U(p,f) + \delta$ for all large enough $n$.

Comment: Yeah，but I dot not know how to do that@DanielFischer

Comment: Let's say that $p$ has $k$ partition points. On all intervals of the partition corresponding to $\varphi_n$ which don't contain any of these $k$ points, you know that $\varphi^n \leqslant \psi_p$, where $\psi_p$ is the step function corresponding to $U(p,f)$. On the remaining intervals, you have an upper bound ($\sup \{ f(x) : x \in [a,b]\}$), so you can estimate the contribution to $\int\varphi^n\,dx$ from those intervals. There are at most $2k-2$ intervals containing a point from $p$.

Comment: Why not just use the fact that each $U(P,f)$ is the integral of a step function $\ge f.?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each $U(P,f)$ is the integral of a step function $s(P,f)$ such that $s(P,f)\ge f.$ Because $f$ is Riemann integrable, for each $n$ there is a partition $P_n$ such that

$$\int_a^b f \le U(P_n,f) = \int_a^b s(P_n,f) < \int_a^b f + 1/n.$$

The step functions $s(P_n,f)$ then do what you want from above. If you want them to be decreasing, let $Q_n = P_1 \cup P_2 \cup \cdots \cup P_n$ and use $s(Q_n,f)$. The argument for step functions from below is similar.

Comment: That is neat! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Keith If you like the answer, you might think of giving it a √.

Comment: Sorry，I thought I checked it before.